# Can I invoke IE developer tools from javascript?

Tags: ie-developer-tools

I'm developing a web page that runs in an IE browser that is embedded in another application.  All  of the tool bars are turned off and the F12 key will not invoke the IE developer tools.  Is there a way to invoke it via JavaScript perhaps through the BOM?

Comment: Can I ask why you wouldn't debug the site and the application separately?

Comment: the question is very vague, what language is the app written in, how is webview embedded into it?

Comment: @CBauer I assume debugging a page is a feature of the app

Comment: @andrew Per the OP, he says that he is `developing a web page that runs in an IE browser that is embedded in another application`, I don't think he's developing the application.

Comment: The host application is third-party and I don't have access to its code.  It provides access to data and context information that is only available when the host is running my HTML/JS.  Partial debugging is possible by running the page independently but certain data-dependent scenarios arise in which it would be helpful to run the debugger from within the host app.

Answer (score 1):

If IE/MSHTML component (as a WebOC or similar) is hosted in another application then the tools aren't part of that component and can't be started from it, code running in it or the hosting application.

You have two options:

You can attach Visual Studio to the control to debug it. Just use `Attach to Process` from the `Debug` menu and select the process and set the `Debug Engine` to `Script`.

You can also attach the F12 tools to it. On Windows (post Win8.1( you can find the F12 tools over at `c:\windows\system32\f12` from there run `F12Chooser.exe` or `IEChooser.exe` (depending on your Windows version). Once the tool is loaded you should see a list of all the places MSHTML is running, just select the relevant tile and the normal F12 tools will load targetting it. From there you can inspect, debug, and profile with them as if you launched them from the app (you can't dock etc.).